# Raspberry Pi 3 - Aircard A313u wwan support?

Tags: modem

Has anyone had success with bringing up Sierra Wireless Aircard A313u USB-WWAN module?  (aka  AT&T Momentum 4g). It used to work with RPi2 and does not work with RPi3.

When the USB card is inserted, wwan0 interface appears, but it does not send/receive any packets.

```
Apr  8 20:45:57 raspberrypi kernel: [ 8068.827027] 
        sierra_net 1-1.4:1.7 wwan0: register 'sierra_net' 
        at usb-3f980000.usb-1.4, Sierra Wireless USB-to-WWAN Modem
```

(The USB gadget works well on a Windows laptop)